# How can I enable download link in the Media browser library tab

Tags: 7, media

My media browser has a list of powerpoint and visio files:

[image: Media Browser Library tab]

**How can I add a download link or preview it next to each file?** The idea is to make it easier for user to choose which file they want before saving the content. I am using media module 7x-2.8.

Comment: Just to add, I saw the "Media Browser" view but the "fields" are showing "the selected style or row format does not utilize fields.". I'm not sure if the only way to customise it is to implement hook_media_browser_plugin_info() and hook_media_browser_plugin_view()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this to resolve the query.

- Copied the entire function `theme_media_thumbnail` from `sites/all/modules/media/includes/media.theme.inc` into `sites/all/themes/mytheme/template.php`
- Renamed the function to `mytheme_media_thumbnail`
- Added these lines before this line `return $output`:

  `if ($element['#file']->type=='document') {
      // add download link below the file
      $url = file_create_url($element['#file']->uri);
      $output .= '<br />'.l('Download', $url);
  }`

These sites were useful during my research:

- How to add a custom View Library https://www.drupal.org/node/1547884. I didn't need to do this as I cannot add any custom fields to these "media browser"-view
- Add a list view in the media library selector widget https://www.drupal.org/node/1806812. I took this method and put the custom function in my template.

Answer (score 0):

1 Create your view, add the fields you'd like displayed.

2 On the "Content: Video" field settings, choose the "preview" option under formatter - this displays the thumbnail.

3 Add the "Content: Path" field to your view

4 Uncheck the settings for label, check the box for "exclude from display"

5 Click on rewrite results and select "Use Absolute Link"

6 Next you'll need to reorder your fields so that "Content: Path" is above "Content: Video".

7 Edit your Content: Video settings.

8 Go to rewrite results and check "Output This Field as a Link".

9 Put [path] as the link path.

10 Save it.

You are done.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me. The cck field can only accept those view with format="media browser". But if I select that format in the view, it cannot accept any custom fields.